# Rails Console: where are helper and app defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

In `rails console`, two objects are available: `app` and `helper`.  [Several](http://errtheblog.com/posts/24-irb-mix-tape) [blog](http://rors.org/2009/12/20/10-rails-console-tricks) [posts](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3176-three-quick-rails-console-tips) cover what these are useful for.  Unfortunately, they're not available in the source code of a normal Rails application.

Where are these methods defined, or how can I use them inside of Rails apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TLDR

```
.../gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/console/app.rb
.../gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/console/helpers.rb
```

## Long version

I'm covering how I discovered this information and what the declarations look like.

The How:

```
# in rails console
1.9.3p194 :019 > a = self
 => main
1.9.3p194 :020 > a.method :helper
 => #<Method: Object(Rails::ConsoleMethods)#helper>
1.9.3p194 :021 > _.source_location
 => ["/Users/erichu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/console/helpers.rb", 3]
```

Relevant source from that file:

```
def helper
  @helper ||= ApplicationController.helpers
end
```

So `helpers` is just an alias for `ApplicationController.helpers`

The procedure for finding the source of `app` is similar.  Here's the relevant source:

```
def app(create=false)
  @app_integration_instance = nil if create
  @app_integration_instance ||= new_session do |sess|
    sess.host! "www.example.com"
  end
end
```

So `app` in the console is an alias for `@app_integration_instance`, which I can verify is available in controllers

Is it good practice to use these inside an application?  Probably not.

Is this a way to get quick-and-dirty access to Rails view helpers and renderers?  I think so.